# Override specific key of a dict in host_vars

Tags: ansible

I have a dict defined in `groups_vars/all.yml`:

```
users:
  johndoe:
    name: John Doe
    username: john
  janedoe:
    name: Jane Doe
    username: jane
```

And for a specific host, I like to override this as follows in a `hosts_vars`:

```
users.johndoe.username: johnd
```

This does not work, and if I try the combine filter as such:

```
users: "{{ users | combine({'johndoe': users.johndoe | combine({'username': 'johnd'}) })}}"
```

I get a recursive loop in Ansible.

It seems I'm not doing this the Ansible way. I can "flatten" the variable structure, and easily override it that way, but that prevents me from easily looping over the variable structure in tasks. What would be the recommended way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Set [DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour) to *merge*. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
test_11
test_12
test_13
```

the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: users
```

and the *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml 
users:
  johndoe:
    name: John Doe
    username: john
  janedoe:
    name: Jane Doe
    username: jane
```

Put host-specific updates of *users* to the *host_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/test_12.yml
users:
  johndoe:
    username: johnd
```

Then, the command below will merge the dictionaries

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml

PLAY [all] *********************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  users:
    janedoe:
      name: Jane Doe
      username: jane
    johndoe:
      name: John Doe
      username: john
ok: [test_12] => 
  users:
    janedoe:
      name: Jane Doe
      username: jane
    johndoe:
      name: John Doe
      username: johnd
ok: [test_13] => 
  users:
    janedoe:
      name: Jane Doe
      username: jane
    johndoe:
      name: John Doe
      username: john
```

Comment: Nope. This is still recursive.

Comment: Right. You need *DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR*. I updated the answer.